# Implementing a location search in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a problem with location queries returning erroneous results in ElasticSearch.

In our system, a business search engine, every search takes two inputs: a location, and a query-string, e.g.

```
q=sushi
location=Greenwich Village, New York, New York
```

I want the search to show me sushi in Greenwich Village first, then sushi outside of Greenwich Village, but to never show me non-sushi results.

The problem is, because of the `location` query, anything in Greenwich Village gets matched -- lawyers, doctors, whatever.  I'd like say the following to ElasticSearch:

If q matches, then location doesn't have to (it's OK to return sushi outside of Greenwich Village), but if location matches, don't return it unless q matches also (not OK to return non-sushi businesses in Greenwich Village).

Anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to search for "sushi" (you don't want non-sushi results) but sort your results by location (you want Greenwich Village results first).

If you are storing locations as geo points, you can simply use distance to [sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort.html) your results.

If location is just a field, and you can only know if the business is inside or outside of a location, you can use [Custom Filters Score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query.html) query to boost relevancy of the results in the desired location. The `query` part should contain the search for "sushi" and the `filters` part should contain the search for location.

Comment: We do have a center point for locations, and their name in a field.  I'm posting the solution I came up with -- it incorporates various elements of your answer here, and your answer to my other ElasticSearch question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053295/elasticsearch-use-distance-from-point-to-affect-query-relevance.

Answer (score 0):

I incorporated the information on this post and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053295/elasticsearch-use-distance-from-point-to-affect-query-relevance) to to come up with the following solution.

1. Index every 'place' (neighborhood, city, etc) with a center-point, and also index the coordinates of every business.
2. Index the place ids attached to the businesses that contain them.
3. Use a sub-search to convert the text entered into the location bar to a place record.
4. Use a CustomScoreQuery to modify every result's score by the following formula, which was worked out by trial and error:
   new_score = old_score / (1 + distance_between_place_centerpoint_and_result)^3
5. Also query the place id that results from 3 against the place_ids field as a 'should' boolean query.  This gives a flat boost to everything that actually falls within the confines of the specified place.

A side effect of this strategy is that businesses near the center point of the place are considered more relevant -- it is arguable, in my opinion, whether this is correct or not.  But other than that it has worked quite well.

Thanks to imitov for his insight that helped me come up with this solution.